# What are the roles of various files produced in angular bundle (AoT compilation)

Tags: angular

I ran `ng build --prod --aot` in my current angular4 project and I got following files in my dist folders.

1. `inline.6405cab307cfc3c6a636.bundle.js : 2 KB`
2. `main.a799c9fd4322567743dc.bundle.js : 35 KB`
3. `polyfills.b72d4efc376613f94934.bundle.js:63 KB`
4. `scripts.6072021e6a4e32c07d7e.bundle.js:963 KB`
5. `styles.737751caddf6a44d0993.bundle.css:146 KB`
6. `vendor.c85bb23c3f86ba86be80.bundle.js:548 KB`
7. `0.01d7070ba0efe736c78d.chunk.js: 129 KB`

I would like to know:

1. What kind of code goes in each of these files. I want to know this because I want to be able to control the size of each file.
2. Which of these files are necessary for page load in the browser.
3. About `scripts.6072021e6a4e32c07d7e.bundle.js` : I created a new ng4 project and compiled that. There was no such files in the dist. However this file is produced during compilation of my current project (and weights the heaviest). Can you answer why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) `scripts.abc.bundle.js`: generated from the `scripts` array inside your `.angular-cli.json` file https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts

`styles.abc.bundle.css`: generated from the `styles` array inside your `.angular-cli.json` file

`vendor.abc.bundle.js`: generated from the `node_modules`

`polyfills.abc.bundle.js`: generated for older browser compatibility (like IE 9)

`main.abc.bundle.js`: your main components code

`inline.abc.bundle.js`: for webpack imports.

`chunk.js`: for chunk fragments like .png files.

2) All of them

3) Since in a new project the scripts array will be empty, there won't be any bundle to generate.

Comment: I am using two NgModule in my project. One is AppModule and other is lazily loded. 0.01d7070ba0efe736c78d.chunk.js is from that I guess. Thank you echonax. Its a great answer. Could you cite source though for this?, I need to read more about this I guess.

Comment: @SKG I will provide the sources asap (if I can find any), I'm on mobile right now :-)

Comment: Don't forget your promise :P