# Can't find vendor.*.js when angular.io website loads in browser

Tags: angular

Why there is no vendor.*.js when [angular.io](http://angular.io) website loads? [As far as I understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46685321/what-are-the-roles-of-various-files-produced-in-angular-bundle-aot-compilation) it is the file which contains third-party dependencies including angular dependencies. So it can't be skipped. Am I right?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the [**angular-cli**](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build) documentation, you'll see there is a `--vendor-chunk` option, which defaults to `true`

> `--vendor-chunk` (aliases: `-vc`) default value: `true`.
>   Use a separate bundle containing only vendor libraries.

They probably have this turned off, which means the vendor goes inside the main bundle

**update**

Apparently this is not entirely true, looking into their [**`package.json`**](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/aio/package.json#L57) scripts, there is no sign of `-vc=false` or anything similar. It did made me stumble upon [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8586) issue.

> Essentially vendor chunk is disabled, when build optimizer is enabled as this improves results of dead code elimination. And since build optimizer in 1.5 is enabled by default for `--prod` builds the vendor chunk is disabled.

Extra info:

> Because of dead code elimination and tree shaking you will often get different vendor chunk hash even when changing application code only, so it is less useful for production builds now. In development it is still very useful to improve rebuild speed as there are less optimizations involved, hash stays the same and there is no need to rebuild vendor files, when something in the application is changed.